# Recursively Converting FLAC to MP3 Using FFmpeg While Maintaining Metadata and Directory Structure on Windows

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use FFmpeg to convert all of the .flac's in my music library to .mp3's while maintaining the metadata and directory structure of the original files. I've got everything working so far *except for maintaining the directory structure*.

So far I have:

```
@echo off
rem Copies the original directory structure from F:\Music to D:\Music
xcopy /T %1 %2
rem Recursively converts files with .flac extension from F:\Music to .mp3 in D:\Music
for /R %1 %%i in (*.flac) do (
    echo Currently converting "%%~nxi"
    ffmpeg -v quiet -i "%%i" -q:a 0 -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 "%2\%%~ni.mp3"
)
echo Completed.
pause
```

I feel like my issue is coming from having my FFmpeg output as `"%2\%%~ni.mp3"` , however I can't get it to maintain the original directory structure. I have played around with dpni as options for the output, but then it does not convert correctly.

The .bat is being executed from the command line as `convert F:\Music D:\Music`

All music in the original directory has the structure F:\Music\Artist Name\Album Name\Song.flac and I want it to end up as D:\Music\Artist Name\Album Name\Song.mp3.

Alternatively, is there a way to convert the .flac to an .mp3 within the same directory as the source file and then delete the flac?

Comment: Have you tried `"%~d2%%~pni.mp3"`?

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the for /R recurses into subflders the original %2 doesn't include these subfolder names, so try:

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -i "%%~fi" -q:a 0 -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 "%~d2%%~pni.mp3"
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! So even though it copied the original directory structure, it didn't understand what the drive was in reference to without the ~d?

Comment: The `~d` only takes the drive from %2, the current complete path is taken with `%%~pni`. See the section on modifiers in `for /?`

Comment: Please be aware that my approach only works because you have the same folder name on both drives. If they'd differ a string substitution would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general solution that works also when the source and destination root directories do not only differ in their drive letters:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=F:\Music"
set "_TARGET=D:\Music"

rem // Change to source directory temporarily:
pushd "%_SOURCE%" || exit /B 1
rem // Enumerate source files, return paths relative to the source directory:
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('xcopy /L /S /I ".\*.flac" "%_TARGET%" ^| find ".\"') do (
    echo Currently converting "%%F"...
    rem // Create destination directory, suppress error if it aready exists:
    mkdir "%_TARGET%\%%F\.." 2> nul
    rem // Perform actual file conversion, using paths relative to target directory:
    ffmpeg -v quiet -i "%%F" -q:a 0 -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 ^
        -write_id3v1 1 "%_TARGET%\%%F\..\%%~nF.mp3"
)
echo Completed.
popd

endlocal
exit /B
```